Unauthorized error with valid Bearer token from OAuth2.0
I'm trying to setup API on Postman. The service that I use is SPS-commerce and here is the link of developer site. Not only on Postman, it also happens the other API platform
(https://developercenter.spscommerce.com/#/home)
I used OAuth 2.0 and I was able to get Access token. However, when I tried to use it, it gives me an error
{
    "status": "error",
    "error": {
        "error": "Unauthorized",
        "errorDescription": "Authentication Failure"
    }
}

This is the manual link that checking if access token is valid:
(https://developercenter.spscommerce.com/#/docs/new-authentication-docs/using-an-access-token)
I'll provide some pictures that I've done so far.




